# Open tab with specific button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I press 1 of 5 buttons list, I want to display the content of each button in specific tab with `vue.js`.

[image: Here is example]

I'm new with Vue. Can someone please help me, I'm stuck with this from past 1 week.

Comment: buttons, like keyboard? or html buttons? shirt buttons? Red Buttons? the picture of your web page does not help at all ... what will help is the *code* you have an issue with - where are these 5 buttons? you have 6 options on the picture, not 5

Answer (score -1):

You can use Hotkeys packages.

similar:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotkeys-js